# PHP multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I'm slowly back into coding ...

I'm getting race data from a database, and based on a field, I check or don't check a checkbox

For example

```
[ ] Race 1
[x] Race 2
[ ] Race 3
```

Each race can be on/off.
So, I could change it to:

```
[x] Race 1
[x] Race 2
[x] Race 3
```

I'm having trouble to construct my form and send the data to change my database to reflect the choices.

Hope the explanation is clear !

Comment: There's no question here, and no code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="checkbox-form.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="race[]" value="Race1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="race[]" value="Race2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="race[]" value="Race3" />
<input type="submit" value="SubmitRace" />
</form>
```

At the backend you can get a list of selected checkboxes

```
<?php
 $races = $_POST['race'];
 if(empty($races)) {
    echo("No races were selected");
 } else {
   foreach($races as $race)
     echo $race;
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've managed to find a way.

I named my checkboxes `optionFree[]` (note the `[]` for the array). And then got the value like this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['optionFree'])) {
  foreach($_POST['optionFree'] as $check) {
  echo $check; 
}
```